# jQuery if selected value equals

Tags: jquery, select

In my web site form, I need to multiply the `var kwh_production` for a value connected to selectbox items. This is my code but doesn't work because it doesn't check the selected item and just multiplies `kwh_production` to the last value (0.27325)

```
function earn_or_save() {
    var eos = 0;

    // erd modules
    if ($('select_20').val() = 3025) eos = kwh_production * 0.28525
    if ($('select_20').val() = 4407) eos = kwh_production * 0.28525
    if ($('select_20').val() = 5809) eos = kwh_production * 0.28525
    if ($('select_20').val() = 5850) eos = kwh_production * 0.27325
    if ($('select_20').val() = 8724) eos = kwh_production * 0.27325
    if ($('select_20').val() = 9320) eos = kwh_production * 0.27325
    if ($('select_20').val() = 10464) eos = kwh_production * 0.27325
    if ($('select_20').val() = 13649) eos = kwh_production * 0.27325
    if ($('select_20').val() = 15938) eos = kwh_production * 0.27325    
    if ($('select_20').val() = 16326) eos = kwh_production * 0.27325    
    if ($('select_20').val() = 17612) eos = kwh_production * 0.27325    
    if ($('select_20').val() = 21288) eos = kwh_production * 0.27325    

    // europe modules
    if ($('select_20').val() = 3289) eos = kwh_production * 0.28525
    if ($('select_20').val() = 4882) eos = kwh_production * 0.28525
    if ($('select_20').val() = 6410) eos = kwh_production * 0.28525
    if ($('select_20').val() = 9350) eos = kwh_production * 0.27325
    if ($('select_20').val() = 9350) eos = kwh_production * 0.27325
    if ($('select_20').val() = 10481) eos = kwh_production * 0.27325
    if ($('select_20').val() = 11463) eos = kwh_production * 0.27325
    if ($('select_20').val() = 14745) eos = kwh_production * 0.27325
    if ($('select_20').val() = 17269) eos = kwh_production * 0.27325
    if ($('select_20').val() = 18285) eos = kwh_production * 0.27325
    if ($('select_20').val() = 19772) eos = kwh_production * 0.27325
    if ($('select_20').val() = 23653) eos = kwh_production * 0.27325

    if (eos != 0) {
      $("earn_or_save").set('text', "€ " + number_format(eos, 2, ',', '.'));
      $("i_earn_or_save").value = number_format(eos, 2, '.', '');
    }
    else {
      $("earn_or_save").set('text', "");
      $("i_earn_or_save").value = 0;
    }
  }

$("select_20").addEvent('onChange', earn_or_save);
```

Comment: Use == operator to compare values. Use single = for assignments.

Answer (score 0):

select_20 should your id or class and you are missing == when comparing. Read more for explanation.

1. if select_20 is an **id**, your selector should be `$('#select_20')`;
   if select_20 is a **class**, your selector should be `$('.select_20')`;
2. When comparing use **==** instead of **=** `if ($('#select_20').val() == 3025)`

Hope this will help you out. If you have any questions please don't hesitate to ask. Thanks